# How to delete newline if the line doesn't end with "

Tags: regex, sed

Sample data:

```
"data","123"
"data2","qwer"
"false","234
And i'm the culprit"
"data5","234567"
```

Output text should be

```
"data","123"
"data2","qwer"
"false","234And i'm the culprit"
"data5","234567"
```

In essence, I want to fix my csv file (which is very large)

I'm using sed so an answer in sed would help a lot :)

Comment: What if you have trailing whitespace after a closing `"`?

Comment: That's not a problem i think, csv doesn't detect those as a problem and we could always trim

Comment: You need to make sure that your file doesn't contain trailing whitespace before running Ed's command.

Comment: @Jubobs Yes, you're right, there are some exceptional cases where the line ends with spaces. I'll post this as another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed is always the wrong choice for any problem that involves multiple lines. Just use awk:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (prev~/"$/?RS:""), $0; prev=$0} END{print ""}' file
"data","123"
"data2","qwer"
"false","234And i'm the culprit"
"data5","234567"
```

The above just checks if the previous line ended with a `"` and if it did then it prints the default Record Separator (which is a newline - you could replace RS with ORS or a hard-coded `"\n"` if you prefer) but if it didn't then it doesn't print anything. Then it prints the current record without a newline after it. At the end of everything it prints a newline.

Comment: Can you kindly explain it as well, it works though :)

Comment: This will fail on well formed lines that have trailing whitespace. As an example, try to add a few spaces after `"123"` in the original file, save the file, and run your command again.

Comment: Explanation added. @Jubobs The OP specifically addressed trailing spaces in his earlier comment and stated it's not a problem.

Comment: @EdMorton I think the OP is not anticipating that your command would be problematic if run on a file that contains trailing whitespace: the resulting file would not be a valid CSV. S/he would have to first remove any trailing whitespace, and only then run your command.

Comment: There are many possible CSV file contents that are different from what the OP has told us his CSV file contains that could cause that tool (or any other that doesn't use a full CSV parser) to fail, e.g. if the last field on a line is just a literal newline inside double quotes or if some fields are not inside quotes. If the input file is differently formatted/populated from what the OP posted then he needs to describe his real input file format and provide a more representative sample but if it's as-posted then this cheap and cheerful solution will work just fine.

Comment: I wasn't expecting trailing white-spaces but unfortunately there are. I'll be accepting your answer though since it answers the question :)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, with sed it could be done like this:

```
sed '/"\s*$/! { :loop; N; //! { $! b loop }; s/\n//g }'
```

This works as follows:

```
/"\s*$/! {    # if a line does not end with double quotes (possibly followed
              # by whitespaces)
  :loop       # jump label "loop"
  N           # fetch the next line
  //! {       # unless the content of the pattern space matches the
              # previously attempted pattern (that is: unless it ends with a
              # double quote, which is the case iff the last fetched line does)
    $! b loop # and unless we reached the end of the input ($!),
              # go back to "loop"
  }
  s/\n//g     # remove all newlines from the accumulated lines in the
              # pattern space
}
```

Thus this accumulates successive lines that don't end with a double quote in the pattern space and then pastes them together to a single line before printing that line.

Comment: not working on 2 point for me.1) strangely (reading the code it should), the `s/\n//g`never occur 2) last line unterminated by a `"` is never printed

Comment: Both of those cases are handled; I can only say "works for me." Are you using GNU sed?

Comment: I'm not sure if BSD sed understands `\s`. It might help to replace it with `[ \t]` to cover the most common cases.

Comment: No a posix sed, so a change `\s` with space and `;` to NL + some space after instead of before action with an adress but it does not affect the algo itself

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ':cycle
$ b
/"$/ !N;s/\n//;t cycle' YourFile
```

sed version but not the optimum for this kind of manipulation