# How to delete newline if the line doesn't end with " with trailing white-spaces

Tags: regex, awk, sed

[This is continuation of a similar question that i posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984361/how-to-delete-newline-if-the-line-doesnt-end-with) but with another parameter of having trailing white-spaces as ponted out by [@Jubobs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541573/jubobs)

Sample data:

```
"data","123"    <-spaces
"data2","qwer" <-space
"false","234   <-spaces
     And i'm the culprit"  <-- spaces at the start of line and end of line
"data5","234567"
```

Output text should be

```
"data","123"
"data2","qwer"
"false","234    And i'm the culprit"
"data5","234567"
```

In essence, I want to fix my csv file (which is very large)

I'm using sed so an answer in sed would help a lot :)

EDIT: Added spaces to sample text

Comment: The difficult case to handle now is when you have a final field on the line that STARTS with white spaces, e.g. `"     \nfoo"` where `\n` is a literal newline so if that is possible then please update your sample input to show it. The reason that makes it a much harder problem is that you cannot tell just by looking for `"   \n` if that `"` is the end or start of a field. And please for your own sake don't even try to use sed for this - all of the archane sed language constructs for handling input that spans multiple lines became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a line at the end of your sample input that includes a field that starts with white space as it's important to test that that will work with any proposed solution you get:

```
$ cat file
"data","123"
"data2","qwer"
"false","234
And i'm the culprit"
"data5","234567"
"stuff","
foo"
```

So you can see the newlines and white space:

```
$ sed 's/$/\$/' file
"data","123"   $
"data2","qwer"   $
"false","234   $
And i'm the culprit"$
"data5","234567"$
"stuff","   $
foo"$
```

If you just want to remove the newlines but leave the trailing white space then this awk command is all you need (only piped to sed to show newlines)

```
$ awk '{q+=gsub(/"/,"&"); printf "%s%s",$0,(q%2?"":RS)}' file | sed 's/$/\$/'
"data","123"   $
"data2","qwer"   $
"false","234   And i'm the culprit"$
"data5","234567"$
"stuff","   foo"$
```

If you want to remove the trailing white space when it's within the fields too:

```
$ awk '{q+=gsub(/"/,"&"); if (q%2) sub(/[[:blank:]]+$/,""); printf "%s%s",$0,(q%2?"":RS)}' file | sed 's/$/\$/'
"data","123"   $
"data2","qwer"   $
"false","234And i'm the culprit"$
"data5","234567"$
"stuff","foo"$
```

In all cases above, the `sed` command is just to stick a `$` at the end of the line to make the trailing white space visible for this example, the awk command is all you need.

All it's doing is counting how many `"`s you've seen so far (`q+=gsub(/"/,"&")`). If it's an odd number (`q%2` is `1`) then you're in the middle of a field so do not print a newline at the end of the line, otherwise just print the usual Record Separator which is a newline.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like

```
awk '/[a-zA-Z0-9][^"]*$/{ORS=""} /[a-zA-Z0-9]"[^"]*$/{ORS="\n"} 1 '
```

**Test**

```
$ awk '/[a-zA-Z0-9][^"]*$/{ORS=""} /[a-zA-Z0-9]"[^"]*$/{ORS="\n"} 1  ' input
"data","123"
"data2","qwer"
"false","234And i'm the culprit"
"data5","234567"
```

**What it does?**

- `[a-zA-Z0-9][^"]*$` matches all lines that do not have a `"` at the end.

  - `{ORS=""}` sets the output record separator as `""`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]"[^"]*$` matches all lines that ends with `"`

  - `{ORS="\n"}` sets the field record seperator as `\n`

Comment: The above will fail if the last field on a line starts with white space, e.g.`"   \nfoo"`. See my answer for sample input containing that case. I suspect it'll also fail if a field contains an underscore or some other non-alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/^(".*",".*").*/\1/;t;N;s/\n//;ta' file
```

If the line contains two double quoted fields separated by a comma remove anything following the last double quote and you are done. Otherwise append the next line and remove its newline and try again.